# How to tear down shared, infinite Observables with a delay after the last subscriber unsubscribed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

We utilize mutliple services in our Android App. These services provide their data as infinite `Observables`, that are often constructed by combining the `Observables` of other services.
The construction of these `Observables` can be costly. Furthermore the services are often consumed in multiple places so their `Observable` should be shared among the subscribers.

## Example:

- `LocationService`, provides an infinite `Observable<Location>`, that emits the current location
- `ReminderService`, provides an infinite `Observable<List<Reminder>>`, that emits the list of all stored reminders after each change in the dataset
- `LocationAwareReminderService`, provides an infinite `Observable<List<Reminders>>` of nearby reminders by `Observable.combineLatest` the `Observables` of the previous two services

## First Approach: internal BehaviorSubjects as cache

Each services combines the consumed `Observables` and subscribes it's internal `BehaviorSubject` to the resulting feed. Consumers can then subscribe the this `BehaviorSubject`.
The `LocationAwareReminderService` for example:

```
public class LocationAwareReminderService {

    Observable<List<Reminder>> feed;

    public LocationAwareReminderService(ReminderService reminderService, LocationService locationService) {
        BehaviorSubject<List<Reminder>> cache = BehaviorSubject.create();
        Observable.combineLatest(reminderService.getFeed(), locationService.getFeed(), new Func2<List<Reminder>, Location, List<Reminder>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Reminder> call(List<Reminder> reminders, Location location) {
                return calculateNearbyReminders(reminders, location);
            }
        }).subscribe(cache);

        feed = cache.asObservable();
    }

    public Observable<List<Reminder>> getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }
}
```

Disadvantage:

- because of the Behavior subject the feeds of the reminderService and the locatoinService are never teared down. Even if there is no consumer
- This is especially problematic if they depend on Services, like the LocationService, that keeps publishing new items frequently
- because of the subscribe(cache) in the Constructor the Service starts to calcuate nearby Reminders even if there is no subscriber present

Advantage:

- the resulting feed is shared by all subscribers
- because the feed is never teared down, short periods without a subscriber don't collapse the whole pipe

## Second Approach: replay(1).refCount().

```
public class LocationAwareReminderService {

    Observable<List<Reminder>> feed;

    public LocationAwareReminderService(ReminderService reminderService, LocationService locationService) {
        feed = Observable.combineLatest(reminderService.getFeed(), locationService.getFeed(), new Func2<List<Reminder>, Location, List<Reminder>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Reminder> call(List<Reminder> reminders, Location location) {
                return calculateNearbyReminders(reminders, location);
            }
        }).replay(1).refCount();
    }

    public Observable<List<Reminder>> getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }
}
```

Disadvantage:

- short periods without a `Subscriber` collapse the whole pipe. During the next subscription the whole pipe needs to be reconstructed.
- A transitions from `Activity` A to `Activity` B, both subscribing to the `LocationAwareReminderService.getFeed()`, leads to a complete de- and reconstruction of the pipe

Advantage:

- after the last `Subscriber` unsubscribed, the `LocationAwareReminderService` will also unsubscribe from the `LocationService.getFeed()` and `reminderService.getFeed()` `Observables`.
- The `LocationAwareReminderService` only starts to provide nearbyReminders after the first `Subscriber` subscribed
- the resulting feed is shared by all `Subscriber`s

## Third Approach: make the refCount unsubscribe with a Timeout

Therefor I build a `Transformer` that keeps the subscription alive for a defined period after the last `Subscriber` unsubscribes

```
public class RxPublishTimeoutCache<T> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T> {

    private long keepAlive;
    private TimeUnit timeUnit;

    public RxPublishTimeoutCache(long keepAlive, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        this.keepAlive = keepAlive;
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> upstream) {

        final Observable<T> sharedUpstream = upstream.replay(1).refCount();

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
                if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
                    return;
                // subscribe an empty Subscriber that keeps the subsription of refCount() alive
                final Subscription keepAliveSubscription = sharedUpstream.subscribe(new NopSubscriber<T>());
                // listen to unsubscribe from the subscriber
                subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        // the subscriber unsubscribed
                        Observable.timer(keepAlive, timeUnit).subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Long _) {
                                // unsubscribe the keep alive subscription
                                keepAliveSubscription.unsubscribe();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }));
                sharedUpstream.subscribe(subscriber);
            }
        });
    }

    public class NopSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {}
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {}
        @Override
        public void onNext(T o) {}
    }
}
```

The `LocationAwareReminderService` utilizing the `RxPublishTimeoutCache`

```
public class LocationAwareReminderService {

    Observable<List<Reminder>> feed;

    public LocationAwareReminderService(ReminderService reminderService, LocationService locationService) {
        feed = Observable.combineLatest(reminderService.getFeed(), locationService.getFeed(), new Func2<List<Reminder>, Location, List<Reminder>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Reminder> call(List<Reminder> reminders, Location location) {
                return calculateNearbyReminders(reminders, location);
            }
        }).compose(new RxPublishTimeoutCache<List<Reminder>>(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }

    public Observable<List<Reminder>> getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }
}
```

Advantage:

- The `LocationAwareReminderService` only starts to provide nearbyReminders after the first `Subscriber` subscribed
- the resulting feed is shared by all subscribers
- short periods without a subscriber don't collapse the whole pipe
- the whole pipe will be teared down after there was no subscription for the defined period of time

Disadvantage:

- Maybe some general flaw?

## Questions:

- Is there already some other way to achieve this in RxJava?
- Is there some general design flaw in the `RxPublishTimeoutCache` ?
- Is the overall strategy to compose such services with RxJava flawed?

Comment: The third option unsubscribes after the time the keepAliveSubscription no matter what. Ideally the keepAliveSubscription should only be unsubscribed when no subscribers exist so some sort of subscriber counting might be good. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Regarding the *unsubscribes after the time the keepAliveSubscription no matter what*, the `keepAliveSubscription` only unsubscribes from `replay(1).refCount()` part. If there are further `Subscription` active the upstream part won't be unsubscribed from, or am I missing something? I guess your concern was the multiple `keepAliveSubscription` that must be managed by refCount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this was an interesting problem and seemed a useful operator to have so I made `Transformers.delayFinalUnsubscribe` in [rxjava-extras](http://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras):

```
observable
  .publish()
  .refCount()
  .compose(Transformers
      .delayFinalUnsubscribe(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
```

It's available in rxjava-extras from 0.7.9.1 on Maven Central. Give it a spin if you like and see if there are any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the implementation. At first glance, the only disadvantage I could spot is that the `delayFinalUnsubscribe` causes multiple *upstream* subscriptions if somebody forgets to use `publish().refCount()` before that. In such a case the first subscription would be kept active till the last subscriber unsubscribes. This could cause some really odd behavior. Nevertheless if used properly this should solve the Problem.

Comment: Yep that's right. Without `refCount` preceeding there's not much point in using it I expect. The javadoc does explain what's going on so hopefully no-one will get super-confused about it. I might add explicit mention of refcount to the javadoc. By the way there is an outstanding issue with the operator in the case where someone wants to immediately unsubscribe totally for cleanup. API-wise it was getting ugly but could be done. How long do you intend to delay the final unsubscription in your use case?

Comment: I just checked. The longest timeout we are currently using is 1 Minute (only for one service and probably we will reduce it to 30 Seconds). But most commonly its 5,10 or 30 Seconds. The decision is normally based on how frequently the service is accessed and how expensive the setup is. Till now we didn't require any functionality to *force unsubscribe* without waiting for the timeout. Furthermore I think this Transformer could be quite helpful to handle orientation changes. For now we'll keep the `RxPublishTimeoutCache` till we find time to migrate to rxjava-extras's delayFinalUnsubscribe

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a overload of refCount that takes a timeout, which does precisely that